# How to output results using OR in searching value database?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to output the lastname or firstname using search but only lastname is only displaying when i search firstname it does not show values... I tried using OR but it doesn't work

```
 private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from patient where firstname OR lastname = '" + txtSearch.Text + "'", con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            label2.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
            result.Visible = true;
            result.Text ="Showing: "+ dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString()+ " results";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: How are phpmyadmin and .net tags relevant? Please [edit] your question to include only necessary tags.

Comment: That doesn't look like C++ code even...

Comment: because im using phpmyadmin for mysql server

Comment: And anyway, that's not how `OR` works. You would have to write `firstname = some_value OR lastname = some_value`. No shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from patient where firstname = '" + txtSearch.Text + "'" OR lastname = '" + txtSearch.Text + "'", con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ada.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            label2.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
            result.Visible = true;
            result.Text ="Showing: "+ dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString()+ " results";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I have change in sql query in MySqlDataAdapter.

Comment: It would also be compulsory to warn about [SQL injection attacks without using parameterized queries](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries).

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully define both conditions such as:

```
    ...
    MySqlDataAdapter ada = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from patient where firstname = '" + txtSearch.Text + "' OR lastname = '" + txtSearch.Text + "'", con);
    ...
```